# Vue JS - how to watch a pre-populated nested object and use the properties dynamically

Tags: vue.js

I made a component "my-item" which contains three elements: a dropdown (populated by "itemList") and two input boxes populated from the dropdown. This component is considered a row.

I want to get a total of items sale_price from the selected items. Here is the code:

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <my-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :itemdata="itemList" :item="item" v-on:remove="removeItem(index)">
    </my-item>
    {{items}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <button @click="addItem"> Add item </button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label> Total</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="transaction.amount" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<template id="item-template">
    <div> <label> Item</label>
        <select v-model="item.item">
            <option v-for="item in itemdata"  :value="item"> {{ item.code }} </option>
        </select>
         <label> Quantity</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Text" v-model="item.item.quantity">
         <label> Price</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="value" v-model="item.item.sale_price">
        <button v-on:click= "remove"> X </button>
    </div>
</template>

  Vue.component('my-item', {
    props: ['itemdata', 'item'],
    template: '#item-template',
    data: function () {
        return {

        }
    },
    methods: {
        remove() {
            this.$emit('remove');
        }
    }
}),

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        items: [],
        itemList: [{"id":1,"code":"1001","name":"Tiles 2929","cost_price":1000,"sale_price":1100,"branch_id":2,"condition":"Good","quantity":200,"created_at":"2018-04-10 11:26:07","updated_at":"2018-04-12 06:25:08"},{"id":2,"code":"1002","name":"Sliding Doors","cost_price":20000,"sale_price":22000,"branch_id":1,"condition":"Good","quantity":50,"created_at":"2018-04-12 06:25:50","updated_at":"2018-04-12 06:25:50"}],
        transaction: {
            customer: '',
            branch: '',
            mode_of_payment: '',
            discount: '',
            amount: 0
        }
    },

    methods: {

         addItem: function(){
                this.items.push({item: ''}); 
        },
        removeItem: function(index){
                this.items.splice(index,1);
            }

    },
     watch:{
            items: {
                handler: function () {
                    if(Object.keys(this.items).length > 0) {

                        for(var i in this.items){
                            this.transaction.amount += i.item.sale_price
                        } 
                    }
                },
                deep: true
            }
        }
})
```

The console always returns "i.item.sale_price is undefined" please help

Sorry for the errors. This is my first time here

I can't seem to arrange the code well. But here's the link to the file
[Link](https://jsbin.com/saziyur/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Did you mean to iterate over an Array using `for(var i in this.items)`? `for ... of` is for `arrays`, `for ... in` is for `objects`.

Comment: wow thanks. that was exactly what i have been missing. it worked